# What is confluence?

Tags: computer-science, relations

I got a worksheet at university last week, and the first task is:

A relation $R$ of a set $M$ is confluent, if

$ \forall x \in M  \forall w_1,w_2 \in M :((xRw_1 \land xRw_2 ) \to \exists z \in M (w_1Rz \land w_2Rz)) $ .

I don't get it. What is the relationship between $z$ and $w_1$, $w_2$ and $x$? They are all part of the same set but why implicate the first 2 relations $w_1Rz$ and $w_2Rz$ and how do I recognize if a set is confluent?

Thanks for your help!

PS: This is just the "introduction" to the task, which I want to do on my own.

Comment: What you quoted is a **definition**. Given a relation $R$, you check whether the condition holds. If it holds, you call the relation "confluent". (Note, the terminology applies to the relation $R$, not the set $M$.)

Comment: Intuitively it tells you that whenever something is related to both $w_1, w_2$, then $w_1$ and $w_2$ are related to something too.

Comment: I am trying to picture confluence with a directed graph, where $x R y$ if there is a directed edge from vertex $x$ to vertex $y$.  Then the definition says that if you have directed edges from some vertex $x$ to $w_1$ and to $w_2$, then there will be a vertex $z$ such that there are directed edges from $w_1$ and $w_2$ to $z$.  When you draw it, you see two 'rivers' flowing from $x$ to $w_1$ and $w_2$, and then flowing back together (confluence) into $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confluence is a property that a relation on a set may or may not have (as Willie Wong commented, what you wrote is a *definition*, not a statement about some specific relation where you can check if the property holds or not).

Intuitively, as paw88789 comments, a relation is confluent if every time it branches off at some element $x$ to some elements $w_1$ and $w_2$, then it eventually closes back at a later element $z$. You might want to look up [the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28abstract_rewriting%29) for starters.