# What is a poset called, when all elements with a lower bound, also share a upper bound?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I have a partially ordered $M$ set that satisfies:

- For all $a, b, l \in M$, if $l \leq a$ and $l \leq b$ then there exists $u$, s.t. $a \leq u$ and $b \leq u$.

The property is strictly weaker than a lattice, even weaker than a union of lattices. Does it have a name?

What if the order is a pre-order?

Comment: If $u$ was required to be a *least* upper bound, then this property would be the existence of pushouts, viewing the poset as a category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property is most commonly known as the *confluence of $\leq$*. It is used mostly in the context of [term rewriting systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_(abstract_rewriting)), but is occasionally used in other contexts as well; see, for instance, [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993215/what-is-confluence) or [this MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Confluent.html), found by Googling the term. Note that the stars which occasionally appear in these definitions are the reflexive-transitive closures of the relations being discussed, but the reflexive-transitive closure of an order relation is of course just that relation itself, as it is already reflexive and transitive.